# How robust is client side security and validation?

Tags: security, web, client-server, web-development-server, websecurity

We use client side form validation and we manage web page access using things like Authguard in Angular.

But how secure is this, can't clients directly manipulate the java scripts from their side and access any web page that is already loaded and send any unvalidated data to the server?

Is it only useful for the benign clients and is not useful against malicious clients? Or is there more to it?

Is there any other way to make the code of client side more secure and control what clients do even after the they have loaded all the web pages?

Answer (score 1):

It's only useful for user experience, not for security.

In fact, you can't even assume that the client is a web browser, or that it's even running your code. You can't secure the server side from the client side, unless you have a way to vet each and every client device (e.g. with [perimeter security](https://www.barracuda.com/glossary/network-perimeter)).

Even after a user has logged in, that doesn't necessarily count as a vetted device, since it's possible to [steal authentication cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting#Persistent_attack).
...unless you properly secure the server.